# Undefined method for UserMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got an app where users submit weeks which can be approved or denied, and in my weeks controller I have the following lines meant to iterate over the selected weeks, find their corresponding users and send each user an email:

```
elsif params[:commit] == "Reject selected weeks"
  user_week = Week.where(id: params[:weeks_ids])
  user_week.update_all(approved?: false)

  # fetch the set of user_emails by converting the user_weeks to user_ids
  users = User.find(user_week.pluck(:user_id))
  users.each do |user|
    #iterate over the users and send each one an email
    UserMailer.send_rejection(user).deliver
  end
  flash[:info] = "Selected weeks were Rejected."
  end
  redirect_to weeks_path
```

When I attempt to reject a week, I receive the following error message:

```
undefined method `send_rejection' for UserMailer:Class
```

I'm adding on to pre-existing code and have little knowledge of MVC, so the only issues I can think of would be with placing the mailer method in the wrong file or sending an incorrect type of arg to the mailer method. 
Here is "send_rejection", the mailer contained in my user model.

```
def send_rejection(user)
  UserMailer.reject_timesheet(user).deliver_now
end
```

The corresponding method in my user_mailer.rb file:

```
def reject_timesheet(user)
  @greeting = "Hi"
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Rejected Timesheet"
end
```

New to rails and not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried placing the send_rejection method inside user_mailer.rb instead of the User model?  I think using UserMailer. makes it look in there.  Or just do UserMailer.reject_timesheet.

Comment: Killer, you're right

Comment: The upper case bit is calling that file.  User. calls the user model,  UserMailer is calling the userMailer (this is at the very top of the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem of MVC, one question I'd probably ask is why are you not calling the `reject_timesheet` directly instead of `send_rejection`.
You're getting the error because as you said the method is defined in the user model, so in order to call the method, you'd need to do:

```
user.send_rejection
```

In which case I doubt you'd be needing to pass a user argument to the `send_rejection`, as you could just do:

```
class User
  def send_rejection
    UserMailer.reject_timesheet(self).deliver_now
  end
end
```

then in your controller:

```
...
  users.each do |user|
    #iterate over the users and send each one an email
    user.send_rejection
  end
...
```

I believe you could also clean up your codebase a bit and possibly refactor some logic, but basically this approach should resolve your errors.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks! @Rockwell suggested a similar fix and it worked. I'll give this more detailed approach a shot and accept in a sec